# How to use JS file for a particular part of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to use jQuery file for specific part of body. Because i changed the original version of jQuery tools file and i want to use both file(changed and original) in a Html page

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jQuery.noConflict()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) was added in `**v1.1**` to support loading jQuery on a page with other code that uses the `global **$** variable`; and to make it easy to load multiple versions of jQuery on the same page

**For Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

For detail explanation and tutorial. Please visit following:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

[Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery's `noConflict()` function. This way you can assign one version of jQuery to `$` and a second one to any var: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/